# HTTP Client capable of logging in and maintaining a session in production

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, watir

I am trying to build a bot that uses credentials to log in and activate some javascript elements on the page.

The site that I am botting does not have an API that I can use and the site itself is very JS heavy.

Is it possible using something like, [Tesla](https://hex.pm/packages/tesla) to log in as a user and interact with a browser, much like Watir and Capybara do, but in a production environment?

I am new to Elixir, but I imagine I would use a long running GenServer that would login on init. Most of the users use 2FA, which can be authorized when the user logs in, but if the bot wants to run days from the time the user logged in, it would have to store the auth session/token.

I have built the bot successfully using Watir, the testing framework. It open a browser and physically logs in. Then it proceeds with the bot successfully. But if I switch to a headless driver the JS doesn't execute properly.

Is it possible to put something like this into production?

Comment: "headless driver the JS doesn't load" I'm not following this. chromedriver and geckodriver both support headless that loads the JS just fine, and both work with any Selenium/Watir code.

Comment: What headless driver is that? Anything less than Phantom most probably will fail to execute the JS the way it was intended to in a full browser.

Comment: I was using PhantomJS and I could only get it working about 80% of the time due to how to JS was executing. That's why I switched to Watir. (as a temp solution while I debating whether this app was going to go into production)

Comment: I assume you tried with chrome/ium headless?

Comment: I have, but my experience has been with Rails only, and the only time I have ever used chromium or phantomjs was to test. I have never executed it within a production app, so I could just be going about it wrong.

Comment: @JoeMarion well, using chrome/ium on tests or without tests should be the same. In Elixir if you want to have most of the capybara functions you probably would use Wallaby (or a slightly different dsl with Hound). Any of these should work. If you want multiple simultaneous sessions then things become a bit more difficult to manage through the regular selenium/webdriver interface and you'll probably need to go deeper on how to communicate with selenium/use selenium itself, or launch chrome yourself and manipulate the browser through other means

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hound](https://github.com/HashNuke/hound) or [Wallaby](https://github.com/keathley/wallaby) to do this. They are pretty similar. I think Wallaby is a little closer to Capybara in syntax. It's a little dated, but here's [a discussion on the difference between Wallaby and Hound](https://elixirforum.com/t/wallaby-vs-hound/443/4).

I have used Hound for this before, and it worked well. I did have to use Chromium though instead of PhantomJS, because, like you, the pages I was visiting were js heavy, and some things just didn't work in PhantomJS. I used the non-headless (headed?) Chromium to develop so I could see what was going on, then switched to headless without issue once I got everything setup.

In regards to running it in production, I only ran the bot locally, but I see no reason why you couldn't get it working locally then deploy to an EC2 instance with the same setup and run it.